# Will using this mains EMI filter exceed maximum earth leakage when used together with an AC/DC converter

Tags: mains, emi-filtering, leakage-current

For an industrial piece of equipment with AC power inlet, I want to use [this internal AC/DC converter](https://datasheet.octopart.com/VGS-75D-12-CUI-datasheet-149897664.pdf) with a given maximum earth leakage current of 2 mA at 250VAC.

Now it was suggested to also use a mains filter to have more safety with respect to conducted emissions, e.g. [this mains filter module](https://media.digikey.com/PDF/Data%20Sheets/Delta%20PDFs/06AE2.pdf), with given leakage of max 0.45 mA per line.

1. Am I right that this can lead to a maximum of 2.9 mA earth leakage at 250VAC?
2. Will this present a regulatory problem for an industrial piece of measurement equipment? Somewhere in my memory I had the number that earth leakage should be below 2 mA. Upon googling, I found even lower numbers such as 0.5 mA, which would be even difficult to achieve with the converter alone (with no additional mains filter).

[Google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20is%20the%20maximum%20earth%20leakage%20for%20a%20class%201%20appliance%3F%20) that the maximum earth leakage in Class I equipment is **5 mA**.

Comment: The power supply is said to be compliant with certain regulatory standards already. Are you sure you need more filtering?

Comment: No I am not sure unfortunately. There will be about 10 cm mains cabling inside the chassis. The mains filter suggestion was more of a "cant't-hurt"-suggestion from a colleague, but then I was wondering if it indeed could hurt, namely due to the earth leakage.

Comment: 2 mA sounds unpleasant to the end user. More pain than tingling sensation. Where will it be sold (which markets)? Any IEC norm you need to comply with?

Comment: @winny I need to comply with the Low Voltage Directive for CE. The directive mentions 61010-1 with maximum current of touchable surfaces of 0.5mA RMS. But I cannot find the impedance this is measured with. Obviously the chassis is connected to the earth lead. So if the test impedance is not a dead short to Earth, most of the leakage current will flow down the earth lead of the 3 prong mains adapter.

Comment: @winny I actually found an attachment that specifies a 2 kOhm impedance for touching current measurements. In that case: Essentially all of the earth leakage current will flow down the earth wire. In the case of a single fault, 3.5mA RMS (5mA pk) touching current are permitted.

Comment: Sounds like a near death experience for the average home wife.