# When talking of mains leakage current, presumably this is an AC phenomenon. Can it cancel and/or is it filterable?

Tags: ac, mains, leakage-current

I have recently learned that switching power supplies tend to push up to the limit of 3.5 mA leakage to the ground wire on the mains supply. Presumably this is entirely AC, 3.5 mA RMS, and there is no net DC current flow to/from ground.

Since it is a question of noise with no continuous DC current, it seems plausible that there could be a noise suppression on the mains supply lines that could reduce or eliminate the residual current that adds to the leakage budget on a RCD.

Further, I suppose the leakage may not necessarily be on the supply frequency or even in phase with it, can multiple devices on a circuit have leakage noise that interact either constructively or destructively, amplifying or cancelling the leakage current?

Comment: That’s above the legal limit! 750 uA for class I appliances and 250 uA for class II.

Comment: It's actually the noise suppression circuits that cause this leakage current.

Comment: @winny I have asked a similar question recently about the additional 50 Hz leakage introduced by the mains filter. regulations seem to have changed often in recent years..And as far as I remember the current limit is in the mA range, possibly even 5 mA. But it differs strongly by device typ and working environment.

Comment: @tobalt The limits I referenced are for consumer appliances.

Comment: @winny If you feel qualified, I would also still welcome an answer to my question here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593240/will-using-this-mains-emi-filter-exceed-maximum-earth-leakage-when-used-together Sorry if this is against the site rules.